# Use File.listFiles() with Extension of File Class

Tags: java, file, oop

My question is, in short, how do I convert File objects returned by File.listFiles() to an extended class of File? I'm putting the returned objects into an ArrayList. My first thought was to cast the file objects to my class, Figure.class.

```
for(final File file : dir.listFiles()) {
    fileArrayList.add((Figure) file)
}
```

This throws a java.lang.ClassCastException. Then I thought only encapsulate a file within the Figure class. Doing this I created a new Figure object for each file. This threw a lot of memory related errors.

How do I achieve using File.listFiles() to enable me to use my own File class extension?

Comment: File.listFiles() can never return you instances of your **Figure class** because File.listFiles() returns you all the instances of **File** class and not **Figure class**, each File object must have been declared to be **File** and not **Figure** inside File.listFiles() method

Comment: I know that. I asked how I could convert it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to create your objects, you can't convert an existing object into another type of object. So if your class is called `Figure`, you'll need:

```
fileArrayList.add(new Figure(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

or similar (as `File` has no copy constructor, but does have a [constructor accepting a pathname](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File-java.lang.String-)).

Alternately as [9000](https://stackoverflow.com/users/223424/9000) reminded me, you can have `Figure` accept a `File` and then use `getAbsolutePath` (or similar) when calling `super`:

```
public Figure(File file) {
    super(file.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

It depends on what constructors you want `Figure` to have.

> My first thought was to cast the file objects to my class, Figure.class.

Remember that casting only changes the type of *reference* you have to the object, it doesn't change what the object *is*. If the object isn't a `Figure`, casting will fail (as you found). The distinction between *casting* and *converting* is an important one to understand.

Comment: `Figure` can just accept a `File` as a constructor parameter.

Comment: @9000: *Doh!* Yes, I conflated two things there, didn't I? Calling `new Figure` and `Figure`'s call to `super`.